# Why can I not connect to an RDS Aurora DB via proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I setup a Postgresql Aurora DB and a Proxy via Terraform (code below), which is apparently running fine. But for some reason I can not connect to the DB through the proxy. The proxy claims that there are lacking credentials for the role, but if I connect directly to the DB everything is fine and the credentials are working.

I tried this from a VPN and directly from an EC2 instance:

```
$ psql -h [aurora-endpoint] -p 5432 -d [database] -U admin
Password for user admin: 
psql (13.3, server 11.9)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

[database]=>
```

This works, but when I try to connect to the proxy:

```
$ psql -h [proxy-endpoint] -p 5432 -d [database] -U admin
psql: error: FATAL:  This RDS proxy has no credentials for the role cellwerkadmin. Check the credentials for this role and try again.
FATAL:  This RDS proxy has no credentials for the role cellwerkadmin. Check the credentials for this role and try again.
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is here?

Terraform code:

```
# Subnet group for Aurora
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "aurora_sg_group" {
  name       = "aurora"
  subnet_ids = var.private_subnets_ids

  tags = {
    Name = "Subnet group for the Aurora DB"
  }
}

# RDS cluster parameter group for Aurora
resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "aurora_eu_central_1" {
  name_prefix = "eu-central-1-aurora-postgres11-cluster-parameter-group"
  family      = "aurora-postgresql11"
  description = "eu-central-1-aurora-postgres11-cluster-parameter-group"
}

# Aurora RDS postgresql

module "aurora" {
  source = "../modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora/"

  name                   = "cellwerk-aurora"
  username               = data.aws_ssm_parameter.db_username.value
  create_random_password = false
  password               = data.aws_ssm_parameter.db_password.value
  engine                 = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version         = "11.9"
  instance_type          = "db.r6g.large"
  instance_type_replica  = "db.t3.medium"

  vpc_id                = module.link_delivery_eu_central_1.vpc_id
  db_subnet_group_name  = "aurora"
  create_security_group = false
  allowed_cidr_blocks   = concat(... subnets )
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]

  replica_count         = 1
  replica_scale_enabled = true
  replica_scale_min     = 1
  replica_scale_max     = 5

  monitoring_interval           = 60
  iam_role_name                 = "aurora-eu-central-1-enhanced-monitoring"
  iam_role_use_name_prefix      = false
  iam_role_description          = "eu-central-1 Aurora RDS enhanced monitoring IAM role"
  iam_role_path                 = "/autoscaling/"
  iam_role_max_session_duration = 7200

  apply_immediately   = true
  skip_final_snapshot = true

  db_parameter_group_name         = "aurora-postgresl11"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.aurora_eu_central_1.name  
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]

  tags = {
    Owner       = "company"
    Environment = "production"
  }
}

# Proxy for Aurora

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_proxy_eu_central_1" {
  name = "iam_proxy_eu_central_1"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "proxy_eu_central_1" {
  name        = "proxy-eu-central-1"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging into the aurora db"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:[account]:secret:[company]/aurora-Pa40We",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_db_proxy" "proxy_eu_central_1" {
  name                   = "proxy-eu-central-1"
  debug_logging          = true
  engine_family          = "POSTGRESQL"
  idle_client_timeout    = 1800
  require_tls            = false
  role_arn               = aws_iam_role.iam_proxy_eu_central_1.arn
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  vpc_subnet_ids         = module.link_delivery_eu_central_1.private_subnets_ids

  auth {
    auth_scheme = "SECRETS"
    description = "allows the connection to the aurora db"
    iam_auth    = "DISABLED"
    secret_arn  = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:[account]:secret:[company]/aurora-Pa40We"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "aurora proxy"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_proxy_default_target_group" "proxy_eu_central_1" {
  db_proxy_name = aws_db_proxy.proxy_eu_central_1.name

  connection_pool_config {
    connection_borrow_timeout    = 120
    init_query                   = "SET x=1, y=2"
    max_connections_percent      = 100
    max_idle_connections_percent = 50
    session_pinning_filters      = ["EXCLUDE_VARIABLE_SETS"]
  }
}

resource "aws_db_proxy_target" "proxy_eu_central_1" {
  db_cluster_identifier  = module.aurora.rds_cluster_id
  db_proxy_name          = aws_db_proxy.proxy_eu_central_1.name
  target_group_name      = aws_db_proxy_default_target_group.proxy_eu_central_1.name
}
```

Comment: `"[arn]"` - this is what you actually have in the code?

Comment: no of course not :) I shortened it for clarity. In the code is the proper arn of the secret manager

Comment: How exactly do you use `psql` to connect to proxy?

Comment: I added the commands to the question.

Comment: Please don't randomly change things like the `"[arn]"` thing unless it's genuinely a secret. It makes it very hard to tell where you might have broken something by providing the wrong value.

Comment: Okay sorry - I edited the arn back in and just replaced the AWS account id and the company name. I hope that's okay like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `aws_iam_policy` policy has no effect. You forgot to **associate it with the role**:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  name       = "role-proxy-attachment"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.proxy_eu_central_1.name]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.proxy_eu_central_1.arn
}
```

Comment: @SiOx No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following **Trust relationship** and altered the **Role (proxy) permissions** automatically assigned to the Lambda Function's Role when attaching the RDS proxy in Lambda Function /Configuration/ Database proxies. The question doesn't specifically mention Terraform -- this isn't an IoC solution.

**Trust relationship**
[AWS Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/)

```
 {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
```

**AWSLambdaRDSProxyExecutionRole**
[The following policy uses the "*" character to match all DB instances and database accounts for a particular AWS account and AWS Region.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "rds-db:connect",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-2:<account_number>:dbuser:*/*"
    }
]
```

}